# Physical process for which Higgs-ing of a graviton could occur?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, general-relativity, higgs

Symmetry breaking occurs when the VEV of some order operator becomes nonzero. But underlying this assumption is that the nonzero value is energetically preferred to the vanishing VEV.

I have heard of the possibility of Higgs-ing a graviton, in which for example some vector field gains a VEV, breaking spacetime symmetry.

What I am asking is, in this scenario, what is the physical reason for a VEV? Presuming we are starting with the theory of general relativity with minimal coupling to various fields, there is no invariant definition of energy, so there would be no sense in saying the VEV is "energetically preferred". It's also not quite clear how to define a vacuum for which the VEV obtains its value!

Is there a physical principle which is invariant with respect to diffeomorphisms which could 'pick' one VEV over another? Perhaps least curvature? Or least action? I guess this question is difficult because we don't have a theory of quantum gravity.